# WSO2 ESB Chinese characters garbled?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I have a problem. My response message contains Chinese characters. So in the console and backstage, all message is garbled.

```
My log:
Response message=== = <message><header><TransactionID>1</TransactionID><Timestamp>2012-09-07 17:06:55</Timestamp><OpCode>IAG.BOSS_SYNC_USER</OpCode><MsgType>RESP</MsgType><ReturnCode>3095</ReturnCode><ErrorMessage>智能卡已被其他用户使用</ErrorMessage></header><body /></message>

backstage:
Response message=== = <″凡琚<header><T″凡琚onID>1</TransactionID><Timestamp>2012-09朵荤ㄦ蜂娇绋</ErrorMessage></header><body /></message>
```

Someone can tell me how to do with this problem? Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

In your eclipse.ini file add the following line:

```
-Dfile.encoding=UTF8
```

After that, restart Eclipse.